# Pivot Table won't sum

Tags: excel, excel-formula, pivot-table

Have tried all online advice.  Cannot get Pivot table data to sum.  Have 2 columns that begin:

```
7847050 CANADA INC                                          4.50 
ACADEMY OF MANAGEMENT (NY)                                  16.50 
ALM MEDIA PROPERTIES, LLC                                   3.50 
AMERICAN ACADEMY OF SLEEP MEDICINE                          21.50 
AMERICAN ASSOCIATION FOR CANCER RESEARCH                    36.50 
AMERICAN ASSOCIATION OF CLINICAL ENDOCRINOLOGISTS (AACE)    16.50 
AMERICAN ASSOCIATION OF PETROLEUM GEOLOGISTS                9.50 
AMERICAN CHEMICAL SOCIETY                                   42.50 
AMERICAN CHEMICAL SOCIETY                                   42.50 
AMERICAN DIABETES ASSOCIATION                               21.50
```

Have tried all advice re putting numbers in number format.  Multiplied by 1, text to table etc. Just get zeroes for the sum column.  Help!

Comment: What country are you from and what is your natural number format= ##,## or ##.##

Comment: Since this does not have to do with Programming, it is better suited for SuperUser.com.

Comment: As @FloLie suggests; maybe the data and your regional number format do not match. To test this, try changing the dots on the numbers with commas and **Refresh** your Pivot Table.